Angular upgrade 15 to 16 Error - TypeError: __webpack_require__.h is not a function
We upgraded from Angular 15 to 16.
We added the required webpack version.
But still this error exists:
Error - __webpack_require__.h is not a function


We tried multiple versions of webpack
We tried npm install without force

